# Mongodb not working in windows 32bit

Tags: php, mongodb

I am trying to install mongodb in my local system..

I have downloaded the latest version of mongodb from the mongodb site and i placed it in my

```
wamp/bin/mongodb
```

I restarted my wamp server and checked in the services to start. But, I dont find the service with mongodb name..

In command prompt, i tried

```
d:>wamp/bin/mongodb/bin>mongo  which gives me a warning like
Error: Couldnt connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 at src /mongo/shell/mongo.js:145
exception:connection failed.
```

Please help me to solve from this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: My knowledge for win environment is not that good, but look at the error looks like mongod is not running. Is your mongod running? check the log. If its not running, first you need to start it.

Comment: You have to actually start the mongod client...

Comment: 'mongod' is the server. 'mongo' is the client. As mentioned above, you need to start 'mongod' before you can connect to it.